# Nginx hsts option disables other security

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I have this configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ...
   # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; ";
}
```

and I have the following in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    ...

}
```

Now if I test my website using `https://securityheaders.io/` with that configuration I pass the 3 tests for XSS, Content Type, and Frame, but I do not pass the HSTS test.

If I comment the HSTS `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; ";` line, I do pass the `STS` test, but I don't pass the other 3 anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `add_header` statements defined in the `http` block are **not** inherited by the `server` block when there is another `add_header` statement at a lower block level.

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header):

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if
>   there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

---

You need to keep your `add_header` statements together - which is inconvenient in cases like this.

One possibility is to move common statements into a separate file, so that they can be included with an `include` statement.

For example:

```
server {
     ...
     add_header Strict-Transport-Security "...";
     include /path/to/common.headers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I should read the documentation more carefully and not depend on tutorial pages so much.